# mean curvature on Finsler Manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $F$ be a Finsler metric and $g$ a Riemannian metric for $M$. Is there on Finsler manifolds a similar curvature to the mean curvature of Riemannian manifolds, such that if $F=\sqrt{g}$ then both curvatures are the same?

Comment: What books are those definitions shows equivalence with the definition for riemannian manifolds?

Answer (score 2):

I found a definition of the mean curvature of a hypersurface in Finsler geometry by Z. Shen in his book: Lectures on Finsler geometry. You will find it in chapter 14. To be honest I did not understand it till the moment yet. If you read it and have any comments, please let me know.

---

The definition is quite clever. Instead of worrying about "normal directions" which definition is not as clear-cut in the Finsler case, Shen use as a proxy a foliation based on a "distance function". Basically, given a hypersurface $N \subset M$ where $M$ has a Finsler structure $F$, Shen defines the mean curvature as follows:

1. First find a (local) solution $\rho \in C^\infty(M)$ to the Eikonal equation $F(\nabla \rho) = 0$, when $\rho|_N = 0$. The gradient of $\rho$ then *should* correspond to some sort of normal direction to $N$.
2. The Finsler structure on $M$ induces a notion of area on the level sets of $\rho$, which are hypersurfaces.
3. The mean curvature is then the "log-derivative" of the area, analogously to how it is defined via area variation in Riemannian geometry.